# Highcharts using MySqli and Json

Tags: mysqli, highcharts

I am trying to write a script that produces a line chart (Highcharts). I have a table of data which contains a number of colums:

Poor, Average, Good, Excellent and Not used

Each column can contain either a 1 (Poor) ,2 (Average), 3 (Good) , 4 (Excellent), or 5 (Not used).

My SQL Query for returning the data is:

```
$query_Excellent = "
SELECT COUNT(RecordID) AS Score4, FeedBackDate  
FROM ".$FeedBack." 
WHERE FeedBackDate BETWEEN '". $Sdate  . "' AND '". $Edate . "'
AND OverallSatisfaction = 4  OR CheckIn = 4 GROUP BY MONTH(FeedBackDate)";
$Excellent =$conn->query($query_Excellent );

$rows_Excellent  = array();
$rows_Excellent ['name'] = 'Excellent';
while($row_Excellent  = mysqli_fetch_array($Excellent )) {
    $rows_Excellent ['data'][] = $row_Excellent ['Score4'];
}


$query_Good = "
SELECT COUNT(RecordID) AS Score3, FeedBackDate  
FROM ".$FeedBack." 
WHERE FeedBackDate BETWEEN '". $Sdate  . "' AND '". $Edate . "'
AND OverallSatisfaction = 3  OR CheckIn = 3  GROUP BY MONTH(FeedBackDate)";
$Good=$conn->query($query_Good);

$rows_Good = array();
$rows_Good['name'] = 'Good';
while($row_Good = mysqli_fetch_array($Good)) {
    $rows_Good['data'][] = $row_Good['Score3'];
}

$query_Average = "
SELECT COUNT(RecordID) AS Score2, FeedBackDate  
FROM ".$FeedBack." 
WHERE FeedBackDate BETWEEN '". $Sdate  . "' AND '". $Edate . "'
AND OverallSatisfaction = 2   OR CheckIn = 2 GROUP BY MONTH(FeedBackDate)";
$Average=$conn->query($query_Average);

$rows_Average = array();
$rows_Average['name'] = 'Average';
while($row_Average = mysqli_fetch_array($Average)) {
    $rows_Average['data'][] = $row_Average['Score2'];
}


$query_Poor = "
SELECT COUNT(RecordID) AS Score1, FeedBackDate  
FROM ".$FeedBack." 
WHERE FeedBackDate BETWEEN '". $Sdate  . "' AND '". $Edate . "'
AND OverallSatisfaction = 1 OR CheckIn = 1 GROUP BY MONTH(FeedBackDate)";
$Poor=$conn->query($query_Poor);

$rows_Poor = array();
$rows_Poor['name'] = 'Poor';
while($row_Poor = mysqli_fetch_array($Poor)) {
    $rows_Poor['data'][] = $row_Poor['Score1'];
}


$query_NotUsed = "
SELECT COUNT(RecordID) AS Score5, FeedBackDate  
FROM ".$FeedBack." 
WHERE FeedBackDate BETWEEN '". $Sdate  . "' AND '". $Edate . "'
AND OverallSatisfaction = 5  OR CheckIn = 5 GROUP BY MONTH(FeedBackDate)";
$NotUsed=$conn->query($query_NotUsed);

$rows_NotUsed = array();
$rows_NotUsed['name'] = 'Not used';
while($row_NotUsed = mysqli_fetch_array($NotUsed)) {
    $rows_NotUsed['data'][] = $row_NotUsed['Score5'];
}





$result = array();

array_push($result,$rows_NotUsed);
array_push($result,$rows_Excellent);
array_push($result,$rows_Good);
array_push($result,$rows_Average);
array_push($result,$rows_Poor);



print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

The result in JSON format is:
    [{"name":"Not used","data":[1,1,1]},{"name":"Excellent","data":[3]},{"name":"Good","data":[1,3,1]},{"name":"Average","data":[1,1]},{"name":"Poor","data":[1,1,1]}]

What I need is a way of displaying the query result in a chart (Highcharts), I have tried to write the script but the results are not correct.

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON("../charts/1-2-4-overall_year_chart.php", function(json) {

chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
renderTo: 'container1',
type: 'line',
marginRight: 130,
marginBottom: 25
},
title: {
text: 'Monthly trend',
x: -20 //center
},
subtitle: {
text: '',
x: -20
},
xAxis: {
categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
},
yAxis: {
title: {
text: 'Percentage %'
},
plotLines: [{
value: 0,
width: 1,
color: '#808080'
}]
},
tooltip: {
formatter: function() {
return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
this.x +': '+ this.y;
}
},
legend: {
layout: 'vertical',
align: 'right',
verticalAlign: 'top',
x: -10,
y: 100,
borderWidth: 0
},
series: json
});
});

});

});
```

I am trying to make the chart have a graph displaying the Poor, Average, Good, Excellent and Not used as horizontal lines on the x axis as a percentage grouped by the month.
I have had an attemp at creating a JSFiddle but even this I can't get it to work.

[image: My chart display]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackbox/v34k4czo)

Can anyone spare some time to help me out.

Comment: Your code looks quite correct, could you run the console (developer tools) and let me know what kind of error do you have when run Ajax? Meanwhile fixed jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uy72ebn7/ (too much brackets)

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan Hi, I don't get any errors but when the chart loads it does not diplay any data for April which tells me I have something wrong because there is data for that month.

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan I have just added an image of my chart.

Comment: In each series values are draw according to order. As I see maximum length of array is 3, which means that you refer to categories from 0 do 2. If you need to have a point in declared value (april), use construciton [x,y] (3,3), where x is index of category.

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan now I understand, many thanks for your time. How can I mark this as an answer?

Comment: I posted it as the asnwer below, so you can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each series values are draw according to order. As I see maximum length of array is 3, which means that you refer to categories from 0 do 2. If you need to have a point in declared value (april), use construciton [x,y] (3,3), where x is index of category.